# I cannot center a button beside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was going to make a sidebar beside a div with 5 or 4 useless buttons, but I can't center the Best Site button vertically next to the Button, I don't know what to do. I've tried many things and none of them worked.

```css
* {
  font-family: Rockwell;
}
#go {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #aacc33;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#fack {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}
#fon {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 9px;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #9ce6ff;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fack" class="menu">
  <h3 id="fon">The Button</h3>
</div>
<a href="http://animatedpizzagifs.com">
  <button id="best" class="menu">Best site</button>
</a>
<p>Press it:
  <button id="go" onclick="alert(42)"><strong>Go!</strong>
  </button>
</p>
```

Comment: do you mean center the `Best Site` button vertically next to `The Button`?

Comment: Could you make it clearer as to what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: Here is a list of ways you can vertical align an element: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/FAwku/1/

Comment: Thanks, pretty useful for some things

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `vertical-align: middle;` property you used with the other button to align it. You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dugp5n6q/).

Comment: Oh, wow, simpler than I expected, thanks! I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Mr_Budo Don't worry about it. Sometimes the quickest and easiest solutions are right under our noses.